# How do I prove this?

Tags: calculus, integration

There was a question on my test which asked to prove the following:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin x} \mathrm dx \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}} \mathrm dx = \pi$$

I found out that the first integral was actually an elliptical integral and I had no idea how to proceed as in my it's not in our syllabus.

Comment: I have posted an answer where I have assumed that you know beta and gamma functions.

Comment: I definitely don't know beta functions but I do know gamma functions. I'll try to learn beta functions before understanding the proof you provided. Thanks. @SamratMukhopadhyay

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals), especially the paragraph about their connection to the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: @Weezy: Beta functions generalize binomial coefficients, just like $\Gamma$ functions generalize factorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the definition of [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m-1}x dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(m)}{2\Gamma(m+1/2)}\\\implies \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\sin x}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(3/4)}{2\Gamma(5/4)}=\frac{4\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(3/4)}{2\Gamma(1/4)}\\ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}1/\sqrt{\sin x}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(1/4)}{2\Gamma(3/4)}$$ hence, the product is $\pi$